# How to convert XML file to CSV file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

How to taken by row tag fields `_id`,`_uuid`,`_position`,`_address` in XSL format?

**XML file:**

```
<response>
    <row> 
    <row _id = "1570186"
           _uuid = "D284E0E9-9807-491F-9A1D-21CB47ABED10"
           _position = "1570186"
           _address = "http://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/_4mse-ku6q/1570186"> 
    <date_of_stop> 2014 - 09 - 30 T00: 00: 00 </date_of_stop>
    </row>
    </row>
    </response>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The title of this question wants a CSV file, and the body wants an XSL file. This is unclear, and should be put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a two step process.

1. The XML file needs to be converted into Java objects using JAXB.(Example - https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)
2. Then you need to use Apache POI library to write these Java objects to Excel.(Example - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)